# Python 3 Insert white space at end of sentences Regex Substitution

Tags: regex, python-3.x, text-mining

I have a load of text like this example sentence

```
s = 'The cat sat on the mat.The dog sat on the log.'
```

I am trying to insert a white space before the full stop. 
I have tried

```
whitespace_after_full_stop_regex = '[a-z]\.[A-Z]'
s = re.sub(whitespace_after_full_stop_regex, '. ', s)
```

But this gives me.

```
'The cat sat on the ma he dog sat on the log.'
```

How do I "insert" the white space between the characters I want to keep?

Comment: [`r'(?<=[a-z])\.(?=[A-Z])'` => `'. '`](https://ideone.com/masjOm)

Comment: What about: ```s = re.sub(whitespace_after_full_stop_regex, '. ', s)```?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can confirm your suggestion works.